# How can I pass the interface instance parameter with a method?

Tags: java, collections, interface, instance

```
public void addLot(Parkable p ){
    //company.addLot(new ShortStayParkingLot("Short Stay Lot #1", 50));
    //company.addLot(new ShortStayParkingLot("Short Stay Lot #2", 25));
}
```

The coding above in within a class named 'ParkingSystem' and it allows me to add a new parking lot to the method lots() below. And the company instance came from one of my gui files,

```
private ParkingSystem company = new ParkingSystem();
public java.util.Collection<Parkable> lots(){ 
    // Return the parking lots we have
    return null;
}
```

I have four different parking lots and each parking lot and each constructor has the name and initialCapacity instances, 
    public ShortStayParkingLot(java.lang.String name, int initialCapacity){
        initialCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.initialCapacity = initialCapacity;
        this.name = name;
    }

```
public SimpleStatusPanel() {
    super();
    company.addLot(new ShortStayParkingLot("Short Stay Lot #1", 50));
    company.addLot(new ShortStayParkingLot("Short Stay Lot #2", 25));
    company.addLot(new ExpressParkingLot("Express Lot #1", 100));

    jcb = new JComboBox<Parkable>();
    for (Parkable p : company.lots()) {
        jcb.addItem(p);
    }
    add(buildOccupancyStatus());
}
```

My question is how can public void addLot(Parkable p ) be implemented? Can you even have an interface instance and make it as a parameter? If so, what kind of data type would Parkable p have?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: Java is an _OOP_ language. And OOP is all about _polymorphism_. I suggest instead of taking time to ask questions here, you better take the time to [read some tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), especially the one about [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).